# Is it possible to change all folder icons with in a folder with Windows 10 Pro? Using a batch process

Tags: batch, process, icons

For instance, if I have 200 folders within a single folder where many of those icons in the nested folders had been changed in the past and I want to revert them all back to the default icon—can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

- go to parent folder
- show hidden files
  [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files#:~:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20then,drives%2C%20and%20then%20select%20OK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20then,drives%2C%20and%20then%20select%20OK).
- sometimes you may have to show system files
- search for desktop.ini
- select all files then hit delete

Answer (score 0):

Custom icons are specified by a folder's `desktop.ini` file. Deleting these files removes the custom icon.

In **PowerShell**:

1. Generate a list of the files within a folder and its subfolders by using [Get-ChildITem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3) with the positional parameters for [-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-path) and [-Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-filter), as well as the [-Recurse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-recurse) and [-Force](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-force) parameters:

   ```
   $Parent = 'c:\parent\folder'
   Get-ChildItem $Parent desktop.ini -Recurse -Force
   ```
2. Piping the output from that command to [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3) will delete the files. For good measure, delete the `ReadOnly` attribute of the folders as well, since that is the default state of a newly created folder:

   ```
   $Parent = 'c:\parent\folder'
   (Get-ChildItem $Parent desktop.ini -Recurse -Force) | Remove-Item -Force
   Get-ChildItem $Parent -Directory -ReadOnly -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Attributes -= 'ReadOnly' }
   ```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining it  especially why remove item is there.

Comment: +1 - Nice explanation. Very minor typo introduced by last edit: "Custom". Please flag this comment for deletion once fixed. Thanks.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you were talking about as you didn't reproduce the typo -- I'm visually impaired with a lazy "shift pinkie". When a capital and lowercase form are nearly identical except for height, I don't always catch it.